# Database supports one to many reverse lookup

Tags: database, one-to-many, key-value-store, nosql

I'm looking for a database system(NoSQL system I think) to store user ID and aliases mapping.

Each user ID may be associated with multiple aliases, I need to be able to perform fast look up from both ways. (i.e. search for user ID by alias, and search for aliases by user ID). Each alias also might have some meta data. Also please note that we might have up to millions of user IDs.

Considering the amount of user IDs we have, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use a RDBMS, such as MySQL. Although MySQL could serve my purpose perfectly if it's not for the amount of users we have.

Here's the database systems I've considered so far.

- **Redis**, we can store all user IDs as sets into redis, use user ID as key, and all aliases of the user in a set. Then store all aliases as hashes, using alias as key, user ID and metadata as value. 

  `userID1 => [alias1, alias2, alias3]
  alias1 => {user:userID1, meta: metadata}
  alias2 => {user:userID1, meta: metadata}
  alias3 => {user:userID1, meta: metadata}`

Redis is fast, but it's a in-memory storage. Which means its capacity is limited by the amount of available memory on server. If we go with this solution, we'll need to shard keys into multiple Redis instances.

- **HBase** is designed to store billions of records, and HBase supports random access. Besides, we already have a Hadoop cluster in production. We can use user ID as row key, and have a column family for aliases and metadata. But HBase is not really for key-value pairs fashion storage. But we won'e be able to find out user ID associated with an alias efficiently if we don't setup separate reverse lookup records, like in Redis.
- **Apache Cassandra**. Starting version 2.1, Cassandra supports indexing collections. I thought I could use user ID as primary key, and put all aliases in a collection(set, for instance), and index the collection. But then I read [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html) article that explained why using index on high-cardinality column is not recommended. Which means creating index on the collection is not a good idea, since it's possible that there are no two identical aliases in our system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are metadata unique for a given alias or unique given a userId?